# отобразить путь в bfs на СИ

Tags: c, графы

как можно вывести путь при обходе в ширину,моя функция берет стартовую вершину и записывает в очередь с кем есть связь, беру след и в эту очередь записываю след вершины, соответственно делаю проверки есть ли добавляемая вершина в очереди и достигнут ли конец! на выходе у меня очередь от старта до конца!

Comment: Как без кода поможем ?

Comment: конечно код страшноват у меня, пока что учусь писать! но смысл в том что я создаю массив структур,заполняю его вершинами через хеш функцию, потом к каждой вершине создаю список в которой указатель на связь с той нодой с которой есть ребро! затем я создаю очередь и ищу путь, проверял на 10000 вершинах и 20000 ребрах, на выходе вот очередь есть, а как оставить в ней путь более оптимально, так то можно было взять конец и посмотреть с какими вершинами связь и какая в очереди и ее оставить и так до старта, но мне кажется это бред а самое страшное затем мне нужно применить алгоритм суурбалле!

Answer (score -1):

Обход в ширину

```
vector < vector<int> > g; // граф
int n; // число вершин
int s; // стартовая вершина (вершины везде нумеруются с нуля)

// чтение графа ...

queue<int> q;
q.push (s);
vector<bool> used (n);
vector<int> d (n), p (n);
used[s] = true;
p[s] = -1;
while (!q.empty()) {
    int v = q.front();
    q.pop();
    for (size_t i=0; i<g[v].size(); ++i) {
        int to = g[v][i];
        if (!used[to]) {
            used[to] = true;
            q.push (to);
            d[to] = d[v] + 1;
            p[to] = v;
        }
    }
}
```

вывод пути

```
if (!used[to])
    cout << "No path!";
else {
    vector<int> path;
    for (int v=to; v!=-1; v=p[v])
        path.push_back (v);
    reverse (path.begin(), path.end());
    cout << "Path: ";
    for (size_t i=0; i<path.size(); ++i)
        cout << path[i] + 1 << " ";
}
```

by [e-maxx](http://www.e-maxx-ru.1gb.ru/algo/bfs)

Comment: а в си?) очередь у меня как список ссылающийся на ноды в массиве структур